# How to retrieve credentials of a created Google Kubernetes (GKE) cluster in Ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm creating a cluster and node pool with

```
- name: "Create Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster to be setup with with kubectl"
  gcp_container_cluster:
    name: "{{cluster_name}}"
    project: "{{project_id}}"
    auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
    location: "{{cluster_location}}"
    logging_service: "none"
    monitoring_service: "none"
    service_account_contents: "{{service_account_contents}}"
    initial_node_count: 1
  register: cluster
- name: "Create node pool for system pods"
  gcp_container_node_pool:
    name: "default-pool"
    project: "{{project_id}}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
    auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
    location: "{{cluster_location}}"
    autoscaling:
      enabled: "no"
    initial_node_count: 1
    service_account_contents: "{{service_account_contents}}"
    config:
      machine_type: "g1-small"
      disk_size_gb: 25
      preemptible: "no"
    management:
      auto_repair: "yes"
      auto_upgrade: "yes"
```

which works fine, however I find no information how to authenticate and thus gain authorization for `kubectl` commands executed with the Ansible `k8s` module.

First of all, the documentation is not helpful both in terms of wording and examples. I didn't find any guide, blogpost or else and feel like I'm the first person performing this tasks with Ansible. I examined the returned cluster object (stored with `register` above) closely, but didn't find anything suitable. This applies to both `gcp_container_cluster` and `gcp_container_cluster_info`.

As far as I understand I need to obtain a kubeconfig somehow with an Ansible module which I can use in the k8s module, like I'd do with `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`. I'd like to see if there's a built-in way first before I do a hacky workaround using shell commands in Ansible.

I'm using Ansible 2.9.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the cluster using the `gcp_container_cluster`, the return value will include the [path where the kubeconfig file is stored](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_container_cluster_module.html#return-kubectlPath). You can refer to this path using your example with {{ cluster.kubectlPath }}.

When you want to use the `k8s` module, you can define the [kubeconfig file path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#parameter-kubeconfig) to use for the module.. It will look something like this:

```
    - name: "Create Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster to be setup with with kubectl"
      gcp_container_cluster:
        name: "{{cluster_name}}"
        kubectlPath: /path/to/save/config
        [...]
      register: cluster
    - name: "Create k8s resource"
      k8s:
        kubeconfig: "{{ cluster.kubectlPath }}"
        definition:
          [...]
```

EDIT:
I misread the document, in the "response" section it clarifies that this field must be set for the file to be written in this path, there is no default value for this field.

Comment: Interesting. I thought so as well, but it fails due to `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'kubectlPath'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/path/to/project/roles/role/tasks/main.yml': line 62, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tags: [jenkins_slave_cluster_gke]\n- name: \"Create namespace for Jenkins Kubernetes plugin\"\n  ^ here\n"}`

Comment: I if print the returned `cluster` dict to console using Ansible's `debug`, I don't find `kubectlPath`.

Comment: I misread the document (or it is poorly documented), the kubectlPath field should be specified in the first task

Comment: Thanks for you input. That was my idea as well, but it leads to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66096 which I'm trying to circumvent in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799952/how-to-update-the-ansible-gcp-container-cluster-module. That question and this one might be duplicates, I'll take care of that as soon as there's more clarifiy how to proceed with the task to create and configure a GKE cluster with Ansible. Maybe the bug simply needs to be fixed. I already waited 6 month for input on it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be impossible due to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66096.

I circumvented this with

```
- name: "Circumvent https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66096 which makes it impossible to retrieve the
kubecontext retrieved during cluster creation, asked
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799952/how-to-update-the-ansible-gcp-container-cluster-module for input"
  block:
    - name: "Create temporary file for gcloud key"
      tempfile: ~
      register: gcloud_key_tempfile
    - name: "Write gcloud key to temporary file"
      copy: content="{{ service_account_contents }}" dest={{ gcloud_key_tempfile.path }}
    - name: "Retrieve k8s credentials through gcloud shell commands"
      shell: |
        gcloud config set project {{ project_id }}
        gcloud config set compute/zone {{ cluster_location }}
        gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file {{ gcloud_key_tempfile.path }}
        env KUBECONFIG={{kubectl_tempfile.path}} gcloud container clusters get-credentials {{ cluster_name }}
    - set_fact:
        kubeconfig_path: "{{ kubectl_tempfile.path }}"
  always:
    - name: "Remove temporary file for gcloud key"
      file: dest="{{ gcloud_key_tempfile.path }}" state=absent
```