# Retrieving GKE clusters kubeconfig using API calls

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After creating a GKE cluster using POST to the below api endpoint

```
https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<project name>/zones/<zone>/clusters
```

I wanted to access the cluster and run kubectl commands using Ansible. For this however i would need kubeconfig to be retrieved from the newly created cluster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this similar to what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803541/how-to-retrieve-credentials-of-a-created-google-kubernetes-gke-cluster-in-ansi

Comment: Please tell if you've managed to solve your question with a link provided by user dishant makwana.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call that generates the kubeconfig. Though if you are using the module to create the cluster, you should be defining the kubectl_path field. Make sure you are using the module from the [google repo](https://github.com/ansible-collections/google.cloud). Otherwise, make sure you are authenticated with gcloud, and use the `command` module to run `gcloud container get-credentials` to fetch the config. You should be able to use the k8s module from that point on